# Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[options]

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a strange error. Usually (I did my googling), in this case of errors Angular specifies in square brackets which exactly module/service/provider/etc caused the problem. However here, it says only `options`.

I tried adding `HttpClientModule, HttpModule, Options` to providers/imports - no success.

Tried to follow this debugging guide [Debugging Unknown provider in minified angular javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480591/debugging-unknown-provider-in-minified-angular-javascript) but also it brought me to nothing (no `invoke` on the call stack, just invokes associated with `Zone`)

my `app.components.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Mozilla console traceback:

```
Error: [object Object]
Stack trace:
resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:783:31
resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:754:17
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:831:17
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4952:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:25
ZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:502:21
invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1370:9
globalZoneAwareCallback@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1388:17
```

Mozilla console detailed traceback (when I click on the dropdown button):

```
Error
​
columnNumber: 31
​
fileName: "http://localhost:4100/polyfills.bundle.js line 733 > eval"
​
lineNumber: 783
​
message: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[options]: \n  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[options]: \n    NullInjectorError: No provider for options!\n_NullInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1218:19\nresolveToken@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1516:17\ntryResolveToken@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1458:16\nStaticInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1326:20\nresolveToken@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1516:17\ntryResolveToken@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1458:16\nStaticInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1326:20\nresolveNgModuleDep@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11065:12\n_createClass@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11102:29\n_createProviderInstance$1@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11076:26\nresolveNgModuleDep@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11061:17\n_…"
​
promise: Object { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: Error }
​
rejection: Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[options]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[options]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for options!
Stack trace:
[object Object]
​
stack: "resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:783:31\nresolvePromise@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:754:17\nscheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:831:17\nZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17\nonInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4952:24\nZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:17\nZone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:28\ndrainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:25\nZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:502:21\ninvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1370:9\nglobalZoneAwareCallback@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1388:17\n"
​
task: Object { runCount: 0, _state: "notScheduled", type: "microTask", … }
​
zone: Object { _properties: {…}, _parent: {…}, _name: "angular", … }
​
__proto__: Object { … }
```

Google chrome console traceback:

```
core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[options]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[options]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for options!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[options]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[options]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for options!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1002)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10849)
    at _createClass (core.js:10886)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10860)
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1002)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10849)
    at _createClass (core.js:10886)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10860)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:783)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:754)
    at eval (zone.js:831)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4736)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1370)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1448
```

When I go into debugging mode the last function calling the error is :

```
function defaultErrorLogger(console) {
    var values = [];
    for (var _i = 1; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        values[_i - 1] = arguments[_i];
    }
    console.error.apply(console, values);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the code of your `AppComponent` ?

Comment: Also, my guess is that you use `initFactory` : sometimes using function calls create issues like that (I remember stumbling upon similar questions). Could you try to get rid of that function ?

Comment: And you login component if you can, thank you :)

Comment: @trichetriche, unfortunately, I cannot. However, this error happens before any interaction with the page, so probably, component logic is not the case. The error happens during the load (nothing is displayed on the screen, just an error in the console).

Comment: That's because you miss a dependency providing. Could you just at least give the signature of your login component constructor ? This error happens because one of your dependencies in your module requires `options`, and you didn't import it. The compiler doesn't see that as an issue, but Angular does, once compiled.

Comment: I'm having same problem, but I'm using "@angular/core": "^6.0.2"

Comment: Have you used any option data provider in your project.?

Answer (score 85):

Here is what worked for me (Angular 7):

First import **HttpClientModule** in your **app.module.ts** if you didn't:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...
imports: [
        HttpClientModule
    ],
```

Then change your service

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
```

to

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FooService {
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit**:

> **providedIn**
>
> Determines which injectors will provide the injectable, by either
>   associating it with an @NgModule or other InjectorType, or by
>   specifying that this injectable should be provided in one of the
>   following injectors:
>
> '**root**' : The application-level injector in most apps.
>
> '**platform**' : A special singleton platform injector shared by all applications on the
>   page.
>
> '**any**' : Provides a unique instance in every module (including
>   lazy modules) that injects the token.

**Be careful** `platform` is available only since **Angular 9** (https://blog.angular.io/version-9-of-angular-now-available-project-ivy-has-arrived-23c97b63cfa3)

Read more about Injectable here: https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable

Comment: That worked for me (@Injectable) with Angular 7. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seconding - this fixed the same problem for me in Angular 7

Comment: Why does this work instead of adding the service in the providers section?

Comment: "Beginning with Angular 6.0, the preferred way to create a singleton service is to set providedIn to root on the service's @Injectable() decorator. This tells Angular to provide the service in the application root."

Answer (score 15):

It also might be that you haven't declared you Dependency Injected service, as a provider in the component that you injected it to. 
That was my case :)

Answer (score 7):

If we need to move from one component to another service then we have to define that  service into app.module providers array.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem using my class SharedModule.

```
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [MyService]
         }
     }
}
```

Then I changed it putting directly in the app.modules this way

```
@NgModule({declarations: [
AppComponent,
NaviComponent],imports: [BrowserModule,RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),providers: [MoviesService],bootstrap: [MyService] })
```

Obs: I'm using "@angular/core": "^6.0.2".

I hope its help you.

Comment: I am not getting your point. How did you solve that? And why did it fix the issue?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error and I solved it by importing `HttpModule` in app.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

and then in the `imports[]` array:

```
HttpModule
```

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same error. In my case , what i did wrong was that i injected the service(named DataService in my case) inside the constructor within the Component but I simply forgot to import it within the component.

```
 constructor(private dataService:DataService ) {
    console.log("constructor called");
  }
```

I missed the below import code.

```
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
```

Answer (score 2):

HttpClientModule needs to be in the imports array, and remove it from providers. That section is for you to tell Angular which services the module has (written by you and not imported from a library).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was in using `angular2-notifications 0.9.8` instead of 0.9.7

Comment: Using "^0.9.7" is the same as using "0.*.*" - Meaning the last and middle digit will update on an npm install in the package.lock file.

Answer (score 0):

> *I had gone through the same error/problem* in Angular

[Error Image with screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd30r.png)
**Error Description:** I was trying to restrict route in customer guard by passing the data by resolve in App-routing-module. like this
`path: 'shiftalertsetting', component: ShiftAlertConfigComponent, resolve: {id: '23'}, canActivate: [CustomerGuard]`,
and was getting continuously console error saying that

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[23]:
```

[Error solved with screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSqdM.png)
**Solution Description:**
I replaced data instead of resolve in "App-routing-module" like this

```
path: 'shiftalertsetting', component: ShiftAlertConfigComponent, data: {id: Features.ShiftSetting}, canActivate: [CustomerGuard],
```