# Angular 6 StaticInjectorError: No provider for Options

Tags: angular, angular6

I have recently updated my project from Angular5 to Angular6. 
 The project is building successfully but I am getting the following error in the browser console:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[options]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[options]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for options! ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[options]

Any idea on how to debug these issues?

Here's my app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieModule } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { PushNotificationsModule, PushNotificationsService } from 'ng-push';

// importing notifications module (angular 2 notifications)
import { SimpleNotificationsModule, NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';

import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';

import { NgProgressModule } from '@ngx-progressbar/core';
import { NgProgressHttpClientModule } from '@ngx-progressbar/http-client';

import { GridModule } from './shared-modules/grid-module/grid.module';

// importing components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { SampleRouteComponent } from './pages/sample-route/sample-route.component';

// services
import { GtmService } from './services/gtm/gtm.service';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard/auth-guard.service';
import { LoginService } from './services/login-service/login.service';
import { UserInfoService } from './services/user-info/user-info.service';
import { UtilityService } from './services/utility/utility.service';
import { IdleService } from './services/idle/idle.service';
import { GenericGridService } from './shared-modules/grid-module/generic-grid.service';
import { HttpInterceptorService } from './services/http-interceptor/http-interceptor.service';
import { ModalProviderService } from './services/modal-provider/modal-provider.service';
import { NotificationServiceService } from './services/notification-service.service';
import { Api } from './services/api';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'sample-route',
    component: SampleRouteComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './shared-modules/container/container.module#ContainerModule',
    canLoad: [AuthGuardService]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SampleRouteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: false }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    GridModule,
    SimpleNotificationsModule,
    CookieModule.forRoot(),
    NgIdleKeepaliveModule.forRoot(),
    NgProgressModule.forRoot(),
    NgProgressHttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: 'enabled' }),
    PushNotificationsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    },
    GtmService,
    LoginService,
    AuthGuardService,
    UserInfoService,
    UtilityService,
    IdleService,
    ModalProviderService,
    NotificationsService,
    GenericGridService,
    NotificationServiceService,
    Api,
    PushNotificationsService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  private loginObserver;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private utilityService: UtilityService, private idleService: IdleService,
    private userInfoService: UserInfoService) {
    this.loginService.checkLoggedIn();
    this.loginObserver = this.loginService.loginObserver.subscribe(
      loggedIn => {
        if (loggedIn) {
          const userdata: any = this.userInfoService.getUserInfo();
          this.utilityService.createNotification({
            title: 'Welcome!!',
            content: `${userdata.vchDiplayName}`
          });
          this.idleService.reset();
          this.loginObserver.unsubscribe();
        }
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: You are missing to import a required service. Please show your code.

Comment: One of the things going into "providers: [" is null. This could be a module import issue - You can use console.log to identify what one it is....

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution for your issue ?

Comment: @Alrick not yet. Still trying

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)\[options\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776562/uncaught-in-promise-error-staticinjectorerrorappmoduleoptions)

Answer (score 20):

This might be late for OP but I was able to solve this issue by:

*Adding the necessary service to my providers list under the* **app.module.ts**

Hope this helps those in the future who are about to encounter this issue.

Comment: But the idea is to avoid that by adding 'providedIn' in the Injectable, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

Can the problem be that you have a non static service? If you have a non static service you must specifiy it as a provider in the Component that uses it. It is not enough to specify it as a provider in the app.modules.ts

**Non static service**

Remove the injectable directive in the service (Usually looks like this)

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
```

**In the Component that uses the non static service**

Add the providers attribute and specify the service. You need to import it too, just as you have to do with regular services as well.

```
import { EntryQueueHub } from 'app/services/hubs/entry-queue.hub';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-viewer',
  templateUrl: './image-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-viewer.component.scss'],
  providers: [EntryQueueHub]
})
...
  constructor (
    private entryQueueHub: EntryQueueHub,
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Can you try changing the import of SimpleNotificationsModule as SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot()
I was running into the same error and changing it this way fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the service under providers of app.module does solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Missing some modules with static methods to configure the provider can also make same kind of issue.

For example consider, RouterTestingModule, it has a static method called withRoutes() to configure the provider.

From angular's compiler's and injector's point of view this can be seen as a missing token in the injector.