# How Angular 2/4/6 component methods use into another components?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular6

How to call one component methods to another component in angular 2/4/6. I am using two components one is login and another one is register. In login component i have one method

```
login()
    {
    var email = email;
    console.log("username", email);
    var password = password;
    this.loginService.loginrequest(email, password).subscribe(
          data => {console.log(data)});
    }
```

So how to this login method in registration component?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest extracting this method to a shared service.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {   
  public login(login: string, password: string) {...} 
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Answer (score 0):

You have to do below changes

**1. registration.component.ts**

```
import { LoginComponent } from 'mention your path';
```

You have to create instance of your component in your constructor.

```
constructor(private logComponent: LoginComponent) {

}
```

Now, you can access **loginComponent** methods
I am giving one example

```
ngOnInit() {
this.logComponent.login();
}
```

You can use in above way.

Comment: I am implemented same code
import { FuseLogin2Component } from '../login/login-2.component';


constructor(private loginComponent: FuseLogin2Component){}


  updatePassword() {
               this.loginComponent.login();
      }

Comment: I am getting this error

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UpdateForgetpasswordComponent -> FuseLogin2Component]:

Comment: That's because you might have forgot dependency injection. You have to declare your component in app.module.ts file also. Please check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776562/uncaught-in-promise-error-staticinjectorerrorappmoduleoptions