# Angular 7 : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MenuWidgetComponent -> TripsMenu]:

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

In **angular 7**, I'm facing following issue, where I need to inject my MenuWidgetComponent in home component, I have imported it in widget component and exported in via index.ts. But still I'm getting,

I googled it but, could not found any solution. Did I miss something in my code?

> Angular 7 : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MenuWidgetComponent -> TripsMenu]:

Above error, Please help.

Folder Structrue:

```
ApplicationWorkspace >
   1. GlobalApp > 
       - App > 
         - app.module
         - home Component
   2. Libs >
        - widget >
            src > 
              - MenuWidgetComponent
              - widget module
            index.ts
```

index.ts

```
export * from './lib/widgets.module';
export * from './lib/menu-widget/menu-widget.component';
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NxModule } from '@nrwl/nx';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { WidgetsModule } from '@gp-angular-workspace/widgets';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    NxModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    WidgetsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Home.html

```
<div class="home" background="assets/images">
  <pfj-menu-widget></pfj-menu-widget>
</div>
```

widget.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { WidgetWrapperComponent } from './widget-wrapper/widget-wrapper.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [MenuWidgetComponent],
  exports: [ModalWidgetComponent]
})
export class WidgetsModule {}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)\[options\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776562/uncaught-in-promise-error-staticinjectorerrorappmoduleoptions)

Comment: Where is TripsMenu in your source code?

Comment: @HienNguyen 
I have created it inside widgetsfolder, Inside folder menu-widget > both menu-widget.component files and tripsMenu.ts file

widget >
            src > 
              - MenuWidgetComponent > -1. menu-widget.component
                                                           -2. trips-menu.ts
              - widget module

Comment: Try adding the child component to entryComponents in your module.ts definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed to import TripsMenu in widgets module.

```
import { TripsMenu } from './menu-widget/trips-menu';
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you fixed up:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    NxModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    WidgetsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [
    WidgetsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Anything you want to inject into another component must be defined as an entry component. It's the same as if you were to inject a component into a mat-dialog.

See: https://angular.io/guide/entry-components for more info.

Comment: Hi @JoshHarkema, I tried with the same, but I'm getting this error ,

**Uncaught Error: WidgetsModule cannot be used as an entry component.**

Comment: I'll spin it up tomorrow and see if I can figure it out.