# How to fix ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomeComponent -> HttpHeaders]

Tags: angular

While fetching from API call using GET method I am facing problem like this

> core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomeComponent -> HttpHeaders]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomeComponent -> HttpHeaders]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHeaders!
>   NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomeComponent -> HttpHeaders]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomeComponent -> HttpHeaders]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHeaders!
>       at NullInjector.get (core.js:855)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:17513)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:17439)
>       at StaticInjector.get (core.js:17265)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:17513)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:17439)
>       at StaticInjector.get (core.js:17265)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30392)
>       at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:31577)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:32142)
>       at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
>       at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
>       at zone-evergreen.js:858
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)

Code:

```
return this.http
      .get('http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/leftside-menu/get-left-menu')
      .subscribe(
        (result) => { }
      );
```

Comment: Show the app.module.ts code, you must `import {HttpClientModule}`

Comment: have you imported `HttpClientModule` in app.module.ts? if not then put this line code, `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ]`

Comment: This was happening with me to, I do added the HttpClientModule but it was not working for me. Later I noticed that in the code, I forgot to mention the **Service class** created in that particular component in  `@NgModule({ providers:[ ])` array. After adding it and importing the proper file it was working for me.

Answer (score 21):

Have you imported `HttpClientModule` in *app.module.ts*? if not then put this line code..

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 

@NgModule({  
            imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule ],
            declarations: [ ]
           })
```

Comment: Hi GaurangDhorda I have already added that code still it is not working

Comment: @SaiRamAkuri Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: Yeah issue fixed

Comment: this solution is more complete. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55638654/12097072

Answer (score 2):

Import HttpClientModule in app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 

@NgModule({  
   imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule ],
   declarations: [ ]
})
```

Import HttpClient in your service.ts file

```
import { MyModel } from './my-model.model'
export class UserMaterService {
  list: MyModel[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  this.http.get(url).toPromise().then(res => this.stringData = res as listData[]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if this appears, check what what you have written in constructor of any component.

for example, i for some reason have put there another component, so that was mistake
When i removed that, it started to work

```js
  constructor(
    private chatRoomsService: ChatRoomService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    private messageComponent: MessageComponent //it has to be erased
  ) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, In this case you will have to make sure that you have imported the `httpclient` module in your `app.module.ts` file and if any import your component i.e homeComponet in the `app.module.ts` and add this componet in the providers.