# Angular 6 Unit testing Error of a particular component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular6, components

I am getting the above error while doing unit testing of a particular component. I am a beginner in Angular 6.

> StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[UtilsService -> TitleCasePipe]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UtilsService -> TitleCasePipe]: 
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for TitleCasePipe!/

Comment: Re: "No provider for TitleCasePipe" is a pipe that is likely not imported and used by your DynamicTestModule.

Comment: Was a missing import the cause of the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)\[options\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776562/uncaught-in-promise-error-staticinjectorerrorappmoduleoptions)